# How do I properly unserialize a JSON.stringify that came from an AJAX request in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Disclaimer: I have read and searched, quite a lot.

I am building my data to send via AJAX like this:

```
var plugin_data = [
    plugin_action_button.attr('data-action-to-take'),
    plugin_action_button.attr('data-plugin-slug')
];
requestPluginAction( JSON.stringify(plugin_data) );
```

If I am to `console.log`, then it translates to:

```
["activate","handle"]
```

If I am to return what PHP is seeing, here's what it is:

```
[\"activate\",\"handle\"]
```

Now, running a simple `json_decode` on that string:

```
check_ajax_referer( 'plugin_routines', 'security' );
$data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['plugin_install_request_data'] );
wp_send_json( json_decode( $data ) );
```

Returns null.

I've tried a lot of things. `json_decode` with `true` set on, simply returning the unfiltered value I got from AJAX, etc.

But none works.

I'm ultimately looking to convert that JSON to a PHP array.

Comment: [*Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE **and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @Script47 Makes sense, yet I still don't see the solution.

Comment: I don't think you want [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) for JSON data. Does your PHP instance happen to have magic-quotes enabled?

Comment: Without seeing all your code, it might possibly be a sanitize function that could be causing it, but again, that is just a guess.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Phil is right. Don't sanitize the data before sending it or processing it

Comment: @Phil Disgusting. That did it. Yup, that was right. Thanks so much. Don't code at 6 AM.

Comment: @coolpasta wow, your PHP version must be really old. `magic_quotes_gpc` hasn't been a valid config since PHP 5.3